C# Extern Aliases with 2 packages only working with 1 package
I have a simple setup where I have 2 nuget packges that share the same namespace. I'm trying to use aliases to reference both packages in 1 console app, but ensure I alias them so that I can use both.
My csproj looks like this:
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MultiEnv1" Version="1.0.0" Aliases="env1" >
  </PackageReference>

  <PackageReference Include="MultiEnv2" Version="2.0.0" Aliases="env2" >
  </PackageReference>

 </ItemGroup>


Repo: https://github.com/aherrick/MultEnvRunner
What am I missing to get both env1 and env2 accessible?

The following may be of interest: Configure projects to target platforms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78479488/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-use-an-extern-c-dll-located-in-a-lib-x64-folder.
