In C# how do I use an extern C++ dll located in a /lib/x64 folder
I am trying to keep my project organized.
I have a lot of extern c++ libraries, opencv.dll, libdmtx.dll, etc located in /lib/x64 folder in my C# project directory
In Visual Studio 2019 I set them all to copy f newer, which copies them into the /lib/x64 folder in the executable directory
But the executable wont launch unless they are in the executable directory.
Is there a way to have the c# project check in the /lib/x64 directory?
Note some of the C++ dlls are referenced by other c+ dlls and I cannot modify them.

The following may be of interest: Configure projects to target platforms
